# Axis returns error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, noclassdeffounderror

I have an axis2-based web-service which calls another WebService to get some data. While trying to invoke another service somewhere inside axis2(I can not say exactly where because it's inside some axis2 class) error occurs and gets returned as response:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/jaxws/catalog/impl/OASISCatalogManager
```

So I guess I don't have some library or class installed.

Inside my folder `WebService\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\axis2` I see 2 folders: `Transport` and `WebApp`.

As I know that class has to be inside axis2-metadata.jar and I've checked - I have "axis2-metadata-1.7.1.jar" in my classpath. So I've I've took `jaxws/catalog/...etc...` folders, containig missing classes (I guess), and put it inside axis2 folder just like transport and webapp, but error remains.

There's callstack of my error:

```
[ERROR] org/apache/axis2/jaxws/catalog/impl/OASISCatalogManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/jaxws/catalog/impl/OASISCatalog
Manager
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>
(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>
(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.create
ServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:134)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.create
ServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:79)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDe
scription(DescriptionFactory.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.jav
a:218)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.ja
va:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.ja
va:79)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.opentext.livelink.service.core.Authentication_Service.<init>(Auth
entication_Service.java:42)
        at com.opentext.livelink.service.fnc.ECMCleansingUtilsSkeleton.GetAuthTo
ken(ECMCleansingUtilsSkeleton.java:201)
        at com.opentext.livelink.service.fnc.ECMCleansingUtilsSkeleton.getWSIDLi
stByDPIDList(ECMCleansingUtilsSkeleton.java:88)
        at com.opentext.livelink.service.fnc.ECMCleansingUtilsMessageReceiverInO
ut.invokeBusinessLogic(ECMCleansingUtilsMessageReceiverInOut.java:51)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
ssageReceiver.java:106)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:176)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:1
63)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:409)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1044)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What should I do? Should I somehow configure axis2 to use those class files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `axis2-metadata.jar` in your classpath. Add it and the error should gone.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought, but unfortunately I have "axis2-metadata-1.7.1.jar" in my classpath. That's why I've tried to include classes from it directly inside org/apache/axis2 folder. But no luck.

Comment: @ifuwannaride Are you sure it is in the classpath at runtime? can you tell us how you add the jar?

Comment: well, this jar lies in "lib" directory with other libraries, I've right-clicked on it and chose "Add to build path"

Comment: @ifuwannaride so you have added to the buildpath. Not to the classpath!!! Buildpath will be used at compiletime only

Comment: Oh, so I get it. Somehow when I build my axis2 service with ant it does not include classes from that jar. Although it seems like it should include them.

Comment: Looks like the problem appeared when I compiled axis2 container myself. I've downloaded axis2.war from apache website and my aar worked without that problem